# Python/Tikinter: Can't use a button to update a graph?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Simplified question: For some reason the plot isn't updating when I hit my generate plots button.

```
global f

master = Tk()

plotFrame = Frame(master)
plotFrame.pack(side=TOP)

f = Figure()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, plotFrame)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,master)
toolbar.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def grph():
    graph1 = f.add_subplot(111)
    graph1.plot([1,2,3])

genButton = Button(master, text="Generate plots...", command=grph)
genButton.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You'd have to paste part - if not all -of your code. This most likely has to do with variable scoping. That is: you are acessing objects that are available on the function where you create the canvas, but not available to the button callback function

Comment: If I were to make the variables of interest global, would that do it? (I tried this and it doesn't work).

Comment: Don't use global.  Let's say your callback needs variables `x` and `y`, then define your callback to accept them as arguments (`def my_callback(x, y): ...`).  Then when you attach the callback to your button use lambda to bind those variables like so: `my_button.config(lambda x=x, y=y: my_callback(x, y))`

Comment: Tkinter can hide exceptions.  Where in the callback function did you put the print statement?  If you haven't already, place it at the end of the function to see if its getting through without exceptions.  If it's not, put the body of the function in a bare try/except, and print the resulting exception to see what it is.

Comment: @thenickname: when you're trying to get help in debugging *your* code, you need to show us the code. In general, Tkinter has no problems doing anything in a binding that can also be done directly. You're doing something wrong but it is impossible for us to know unless we see the code

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: The print statement was at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
def grph():
    graph1 = f.add_subplot(111)
    graph1.plot([1,2,3])
    canvas.draw()
```